# UICollectionView not showing images after unhiding it

Tags: ios, swift

I have an `UICollectionView` that starts hidden in the `viewDidLoad`, then when an image is added with the `UIImagePicker` delegate the collection goes "unhidden" and then reloads, here is the code below

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        self.imagesToSend.append(pickedImage)
    }

    self.imagenesCollectionView.isHidden = false
    self.imagenesCollectionView.reloadData()
    dismiss(animated: true, completion:nil)
}
```

the problem is that when the collection shows it doesn't show any image, I have to add a second image so the image can show, I want the collection to show when there are images and to hide when there aren't images, until now the hiding functionality its working fine, but not the showing one.

Comment: Can u post your tableView datasource?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding

```
self.imagenesCollectionView.isHidden = false
self.imagenesCollectionView.reloadData()
```

in dismiss completion handler. Like

```
dismiss(animated: true, completion:{
    self.imagenesCollectionView.isHidden = false
    self.imagenesCollectionView.reloadData()
})
```

Edit 1:
      Instead of reloading collection view in completion. add collection view reload in `viewWillAppear` method based on the array data availability.

eg:

```
if self.imagesToSend.count > 0 { 
    self.imagenesCollectionView.isHidden = false
    self.imagenesCollectionView.reloadData()
} else {
    self.imagenesCollectionView.isHidden = true
}
```

Comment: it happens the same, the collections shows, but not the image

Comment: Im not sure how you are loading the data to your collection view. Please make sure the delegate and datasource are set properly and the data is available on the array.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the methods `setNeedsLayout` or `setNeedsDisplay`. They are related to the view update, and maybe you need to use them on the collectionView or on the imageView itself.